# How to resolve view not closing on .Close()?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I've added a DialogService in order to open a ProductView, so far the ShowDetailDialog() is working as expected.

**Issue:**

I call `Close()` on the ProductView, the view isn't closed. I debugged this issue by setting a break point on the call to the dialog service close method.

When I stepped through the code, the null check shows that productView is null, which prevents `Close()` from being called.

Does anyone have idea why productView is null? (although it's showing data on the view)

**DialogService:**(hosts the Show and Close methods)

```
namespace MongoDBApp.Services
{
    class DialogService : IDialogService
    {

        Window productView = null;
        ProductView _productView;

        public DialogService()
        {
            _productView = new ProductView();
        }

        public void CloseDetailDialog()
        {

            if (productView != null)
                productView.Close(); 
        }

        public void ShowDetailDialog()
        {
            _productView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductViewModel:** (summary of ProductVM, calls the close method on SaveCommand)

```
        private void SaveProduct(object product)
        {
            _dialogService.CloseDetailDialog();
            Messenger.Default.Send<ProductModel>(SelectedProduct);
        }
```

**CustomerOrdersViewmodel:** (Where the ShowDetailDialog() is called initially)

```
        private void EditOrder(object obj)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<ProductModel>(SelectedProduct);
            _dialogService.ShowDetailDialog();                         
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ShowDetailDialog`?

Comment: In the CustomerOrdersVM, I'll post that now. The ShowDetailDialog is working, just not the close for some reason.

Comment: When using `ShowDialog` you need to set the `DialogResult` property typically. `Close` method will be used for non modal windows.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel can you show an example of what you mean, by setting DialogResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by implementing an IDialogService on the View. Then calling the Show() and Close() methods from the ViewModel.

**Solution:**

**Interface:**

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    void CloseDialog();
    void ShowDialog(EditProductViewModel prodVM);

}
```

**View:**

```
public partial class ProductView : Window, IDialogService
{

    public ProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new EditProductViewModel(this);

    }

    public void CloseDialog()
    {
        if (this != null)
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public void ShowDialog(EditProductViewModel prodVM)
    {
        this.DataContext = prodVM;
        this.Show();
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }


}
```

**ViewModel #1:**

```
    private IDialogService _dialogService;

    public CustomerOrdersViewModel(IDialogService dialogservice)
    {
        this._dialogService = dialogservice;                
    }


    private void EditOrder(object obj)
    {
        EditProductViewModel pvm = new EditProductViewModel(_dialogService);
        pvm.Present(pvm);
        Messenger.Default.Send<ProductModel>(SelectedProduct);                              
    }
```

**ViewModel #2:**

```
    private IDialogService _dialogService;


    public EditProductViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
       this._dialogService = dialogService;  
    }


    private void SaveProduct(object product)
    {
        SelectedProduct = SelectedProductTemp;
        _dialogService.CloseDialog();
    }

    public void Present(EditProductViewModel prodVM) 
    {
        _dialogService.ShowDialog(prodVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have always closed my windows.

Here would be my command:

```
class CancelCommand : ICommand
    {
        private NewTruckViewModel newTruck;
        public CancelCommand(NewTruckViewModel vm)
        {
            newTruck = vm;
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            newTruck.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

Here is my view Model and the method that gets called from my command:

```
 private NewTruck myWnd; //View Declaration

//Ctor where I set myView (myWnd) equal to a view that is passed in.
public NewTruckViewModel(ObservableCollection<Truck> Trucks, NewTruck wnd, bool inEditTruck)
        {
            myEngine.stopHeartBeatTimer();
            editTruck = inEditTruck;
            myWnd = wnd;
            SaveTruckCommand = new SaveTruckCommand(this);
            CancelCommand = new CancelCommand(this);
            ClearCommand = new ClearCommand(this);
            SetLevel1MTCommand = new SetLevel1MTCommand(this);
            SetLevel2MTCommand = new SetLevel2MTCommand(this);
            SetLevel3MTCommand = new SetLevel3MTCommand(this);
            SetLevel1FLCommand = new SetLevel1FLCommand(this);
            SetLevel2FLCommand = new SetLevel2FLCommand(this);
            SetLevel3FLCommand = new SetLevel3FLCommand(this);
            myTrucks = Trucks;
        }
     public void Cancel()
            {
                myWnd.Close();
            }
```

This works for me.